# Structure with more than one member per data type

Tags: c, structure

Could someone explain what exactly it means to have a structure that has more than one member for a data type ?

```
struct {
    int x, y;
};
```

Comment: This one could be for a 2D cartesian point. Your question is unclear to me, but that might help somewhat.

Comment: It has a similar meaning to declare `int xx,yy;` as global or local variables

Answer (score 5):

This is just a contracted form of

```
struct {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

meaning that the struct has a member `x` and a member `y` that are both of type `int`, and can both be accessed as `myObject.x` or `myObject.y`, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to:

```
struct {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

This is covered in all text books on C and C++, It is a bit meaningless as the `struct` has not been given a name